# Change HTML table background with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a extension dark mode for a certain platform, but i'm limited to css and Jquery. I have to replace different background-images to another url in table cells. This is very difficult because the table cells have no class and are only in html. Therefore I can only replace them based on the attribute value. I barely know anything about Javascript / Jquery, but by searching I found some code that I think should work. Hopefully you can help me!

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( "td[background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c1.gif"]" ).replaceWith( "<td background="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matti606/smart-school_dark/main/frame_r1_c1.gif" width="15"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="27" width="15" alt=""></td>" );

</script>
</head>
<body>

<table width="99%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="margin-top--milli">
<tbody><tr>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c1.gif" width="15"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="27" width="15" alt=""></td>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c5.gif">
    </td>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c13.gif" width="15"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="27" alt="" width="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r3_c1.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="3" alt="" width="15"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        
<!-- BEGIN content -->

<!-- END content -->
    </td>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r5_c13.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="3" alt="" width="15"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r7_c1.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="19" alt="" width="15"></td>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r7_c3.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="19" alt="" width="3"></td>
    <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r7_c13.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="19" alt="" width="15"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult at all. Just select all `td` elements with `$("td")`. Get the background attribute with `$("td").attr("background")`. Split on `/` in an array. Select the last array element with `your_array[your_array.length - 1]` so you have the `frame_r1_c1.gif` value. Then just set the value to whatever you want with  `$("td").attr("background", "some/new/value")` based on it and you're done.

Comment: Uhm i'm sorry I don't really understand. Can you give me an example code?

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I've made a small quick jsFiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/eobq364y/ Make sure you open up the console to see how it works.

Comment: So if you wanted to use that example with your real code, it'd be as simple as this: https://jsfiddle.net/eobq364y/1/

Comment: I understand it know! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I get this error: https://jsfiddle.net/yprkzc6n/

Comment: That's because not all `<td>` elements in your code have a `background` attribute. You can simply solve this by checking if the `img` variable is valid or not: https://jsfiddle.net/2vhzopqm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieve looping each `td`, getting correspondent URL and get the frameId (ex: frame_r7_c1.gif) and replace the old url with the new one with the same id.

Example:

from:

- https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c1.gif

to:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matti606/smart-school_dark/main/frame_r1_c1.gif

Information about jQuery: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/jQuery

Each method: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Attr method: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Split method can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```js
// loop each td
$('tbody > tr > td').each(function() {
  // $(this) is meant for each td
  let frameBackground = $(this).attr('background'); // this will get the URL of the image
  
  // make this if statement to verify if a background is present
  if(frameBackground != undefined) {
    // split method will return a array we get the last value of array (ex: frame_r1_c5.gif)
    let array = frameBackground.split('/');

    let frameId = array[array.length -1];

    // and we replace our current background URL with ours + the frameId we got from line above
    $(this).attr('background', `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matti606/smart-school_dark/main/${frameId}`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table width="99%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="margin-top--milli">
<tbody>
  <tr>
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c1.gif" width="15"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="27" width="15" alt=""></td>
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c5.gif">
      </td>
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r1_c13.gif" width="15"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="27" alt="" width="15"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> <!-- end -->
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r3_c1.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="3" alt="" width="15"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

  <!-- BEGIN content -->

  <!-- END content -->
      </td>
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r5_c13.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="3" alt="" width="15"></td>
  </tr><!-- end -->
  <tr>
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r7_c1.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="19" alt="" width="15"></td>
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r7_c3.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="19" alt="" width="3"></td>
      <td background="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/frame_r7_c13.gif"><img src="https://static6.smart-school.net/themes/default/images/spacer.gif" height="19" alt="" width="15"></td>
  </tr><!-- end -->
</tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I've already gotten a fix. The explanation is very useful for the future! Thanks for the effort anyway!